# CRON what is correct time code for every 6 hours?

Tags: cron

I just want to know which one should work just fine for
Run every 6 hours forever:

```
0   */6 *   *   *
```

or

```
*   */6 *   *   *
```

Thanks

Comment: Can someone explain me why this question was migrated from StackOverflow to this site? It is a perfect choice for SO and a very weak one for SU -- as per my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

I would say the first one. It will run once every six hours. You can also try to set specific hours like this:

```
00 2,8,14,20 * * *
```

You might also find useful to check out this [page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that, Azure cron is different, in Azure it will be

```
0 0 */6 * * *
```

[Azure cron documentation and more samples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions)